# Clean URL with .htaccess

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have an html page in which there are several DIVs and in each DIVs,I am loading different php files with `$("#ID").load()` function.

Here I was just wondering if I can create a clean URLs with .htaccess (or any other methods) for each of these DIV loads.

I tried googling a lot but got no luck

Comment: Not sure what phrases you tried on Google but `htaccess url` gives me some pretty clear tutorials e.g. [this](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/using-htaccess-files-for-pretty-urls--net-6049) which was the first result.

Comment: I'm quite sure "I tried googling a lot but got no luck" isn't something you have done. And if you've done it, you should have found this: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/using-htaccess-files-for-pretty-urls--net-6049

Comment: @Marty and Rishi : sir here I am loading PHP page in DIVs rather than the whole window.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can but your urls included hash(#). Search single page web applicatons architectures.

Google's Javascript MVW Framework

https://angularjs.org/

or you can try Backbone

http://backbonejs.org/